# How to format currency sign in Yii2 after the value?

Tags: yii2, formatter

Right now when I have defined the currencyCode, the currency sign appears in front of the value like €10 000,00, but I'd like to have it like 10 000,00€. How to do that?

At the moment I'm printing '€' separately after the value, but I'm just wondering if there's any way to automate the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue installing php5-intl and using this way

```
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'et-EE';
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(1202.57, 'EUR');
```

It will change the sign according to the locale.

Answer (score 0):

here i am assuming that you are using span for value and currency. you can check the fiddle.

html :

```
<span>10 000,00</span>
<span class="currency">€</span>
```

CSS :

```
.currency{
    float:  left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rt9r84d/)