# Yii2 - currency format euro

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have this in config:

```
        'formatter' => [
        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
        'thousandSeparator' => '.',
        'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
   ],
```

This print €20.000,00 but I want 20.000,00€ (with € in end).

Who I do this in yii2?

Answer (score 2):

[The main source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992414/how-to-format-currency-sign-in-yii2-after-the-value)

You should set this config:

```
Yii::$app->formatter->locale = 'et-EE';
```

With this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means you need to enable PHP internationalization extension (aka `intl`) on your server : http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Read more about [`\yii\i18n\Formatter::asCurrency()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asCurrency()-detail) :

> This function does not require the PHP intl extension to be installed to work, but it is highly recommended to install it to get good formatting results.

Read more about [PHP internationalization extension installation](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

For example, to install it on Debian :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Don't forget to restart your web server after.